# Configuring firewall via systemd as early as possible

Tags: debian, systemd, iptables

I have a systemd service executing a shell script that configures firewall. The system is an embedded one running Debian 8.

How should I configure the service in order to have it execute the script as early in the system start-up as possible but late enough for iptables to work?

The service file as it is right now (it works, but I don't know if it's optimal):

```
[Unit]
Description=Firewall configuration script
After=sysinit.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/firewall.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to copy [ufw](https://packages.debian.org/ru/stretch/ufw) startup behavior as it does almost the same:

```
ufw.service:

[Unit]
Before=network.target
```

You may also consider moving from your own iptables script to ufw rule list.

Comment: Just for information: That configuration may work, but as far as I understood it by googling, ufw is an Ubuntu thing, or at least it's not included by default in my embedded Debian installation.

Comment: Hm, which kind of embedded Debian distro do you have? It's definitely present on armbian.

Comment: You may not find the ufw.service file on stock Debian 8 in ufw package. Seems like the ufw on Debian 8 miss the systemd service config. But you can take it from the next release (current stable Debian 9).

Comment: My system is built using multistrap.